# Wifi Hotspot Multicast/Broadcast

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

If i turn my android device to a portable hotspot and connect some devices to it, Is it possible for me to Broadcast/Multicast data to devices connected from my Device (i.e. from Hotspot)? If Yes, How? 
A snippet in Android would be great!
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can multicast or broadcast udp packet in hotspot

see detail here:
[Multicast Support on Android in Hotspot/Tethering mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550618/multicast-support-on-android-in-hotspot-tethering-mode/27699370#27699370)